# Making app for iPhone

Tags: applications, app-store-connect

Is it possible to develop an app only for me and my friends?

Just make the app and upload it directly to my iPhone.

Answer (score 8):

It depends. If you have an Apple Developer account ($99 per year), you can create either a ad hoc distribution profile or use a development certificate. For more information on that, view [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html). Although it is called beta testing, it serves your purpose.

Now if you don't have an Apple Developer account, you can use jailbroken devices and Jailcoder. To use this method, follow the steps below:

1. Jailbreak your iDevices. If you don't know which ones to use, google it.
2. Make sure you have Xcode ([Here](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?mt=12) if you don't have it)
3. Download Jailcoder from [here](http://oneiros.altervista.org/jailcoder/download.php).
4. Go through the "Guided Patch"
5. Now develop your program. **YOU CANNOT RUN IT ON AN IDEVICE YET!**
6. Open Jailcoder and drag-n-drop your .xcodeproj file into the box.
7. Connect the jailbroken iDevice and configure Xcode as you would if you had a legit developer account (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/RunYourApp/RunYourApp.html)
8. Click run

An older video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3NAm1MOGabw. Ignore the fact that it says Xcode 4. It works on Xcode 5.

Comment: Nice info on jail breaking. Although I prefer keeping the protections from Apple intact, for some the extra work or risk to know how to secure a jail broken device outweighs the cost of a year of officially sanctioned developer entitlements.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. You'll need an [Apple Developer account](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/) which costs 99 USD a year.

You'll be able to put your app on up to 100 devices. The enterprise program costs 299 USD and allows [ad-hoc distribution](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/distribute.html) of apps via [configurator](https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/apple-configurator/id434433123?mt=12) (for non-development purposes)

Comment: Note that if you distribute them this way, they will eventually expire and need to be uploaded again.